# Add space after period when underfull hboxes occur?

Tags: spacing, line-breaking, punctuation, hyphenation, wrap

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\hyphenation{veryverylongword}
\begin{document}
\textbf{The word word word word word.} The word-veryverylongword word word word word.
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

What I want it to produce is:

[image]

I can do that by using

```
\textbf{The word word word word word.} \hfill \makebox{The word}-veryverylongword word word word word.
```

which, however, is a bit hacky. Is there some less tedious and error-prone way of accomplishing this? Maybe, some command I can put at the place were I want the additional spacing to be concentrated at, like in this case before "The"?

Answer (score 1):

the class seems to have set `\frenchspacing` so the space after `.` isn't enlarged at all, you ca use `\nonfrenchspacing` (the latex default) to allow more stretch there, or you can set `\xspaceskip` to specify arbitrray space after a full stop

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\hyphenation{veryverylongword}

\begin{document}

\textbf{The word word word word word.} The word-veryverylongword word word word word.
\nonfrenchspacing


\textbf{The word word word word word.} The word-veryverylongword word word word word.

\xspaceskip=.3em plus 10em
\textbf{The word word word word word.} The word-veryverylongword word word word word.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do add a clue about how to allow hyphenation of the veryverylongword (if that's hyphenatable except for the hyphen preceding it).